# See devices connect to my wifi router using Swift and allow/block wifi acces

Tags: ios

In short i'm trying to build an App that will grant/block wifi access to my son's wifi for his Ipad and his PS4 remotely using an App.  I researched the topic and can't figure out how this can be done.  Ideally i'd like to be able to grant/block wifi access independently Ie. block wifi to the Ipad and allow PS4.

How can this be done, no need for the full code ( well if you insist i'll take it ) but just point me in the right direction.

Comment: I have not used for specific use case but like Ubiquiti it has lot of customisation out of box and supports remote management via app https://www.ubnt.com

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the router you're using you're going to need to write something that interacts with the router's API, if it has one. If it doesn't, you will need to replace the firmware on your router with something like ddwrt that can be scripted. From there, you might be able to create an app that talks to the router's API.

TLDR: You're probably better off simply bookmarking the management page for the router and enabling/disabling access for the devices.

Edit:

It occurred to me that some mainstream consumer router/access point manufacturers (Linksys, Asus, etc) have companion apps for managing their devices from the LAN side. You should see if such an app exists for your router, and if not, perhaps consider getting a different router that supports such an app.